# What is a Simple Way to Log Basic Macbook Activity?

Tags: macos, logging

I would like access to the following data about my Macbook use:

- when it is active / asleep
- the active application at all times
- certain state information about the active application, such as the active tab in Google Chrome

Questions

- Is this information already logged somewhere (I'm on OS X 10.9.1)
- If not, is there a simple daemon or app (daemon I can launch from the command line) available to do this?
- If not, what tools to exist to access this data? I'd write my own script to do the logging.

Comment: You know about `Console.app` and `Activity Monitor.app`, right?  Or are you looking for a completely CLI solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I've found is the app [TimeSink](http://manytricks.com/timesink/). This tracks the foreground application and window title at all times and provides regular automated exports as well as basic analytics.  Only $5.00 for a license and gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Console and the Activity Monitor comes to mind. For more CLI-scriptable solutions, check out top/htop. You probably need to write your own parser but seems like a nice project.

Comment: Not sure I was clear enough in my question. I want to log the information, not just be able to see state info at any given moment. I know about both Console and Activity Monitor-- Console seems to log sleeping and waking, but not active application-- Activity Monitor provides some realtime info but I'm not sure how to use it to log anything.

Comment: I see. Could you elaborate on what sort of result you'd like to get? Like a logfile or something? What's the goal here and how would you like the data to be presented?

Comment: A logfile is fine-- it just needs to be regularly structured so that I can write code to work with it. The less extraneous data, the better. The goal is for me to run basic analytics on what apps I use when, what websites I look at when, etc. It is absolutely essential that I have access to the raw data myself (I would not like an app that tracks this but locks up the data in some difficult to read proprietary data format).